# Por que se desborda el <p>?

Tags: html, css3

Estaba en freecodecamp,lo uso para ejercitar y aprender en html,y normalmente me explica ciertas cosas o las encuentro en google,pero me paso algo que no me explica,me dice como solucionarlo (Me dice que Esto se soluciona  colocando **clear:right;** en el **.divider**), pero no por que sucede, el problema es que **" % Daily Value * "** se sale del div **"label"** visualmente hablando,**Adjunto el caso en codepen:** https://codepen.io/DemonShike/pen/xxWojNv

**Y en freecodecamp**
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/2022/responsive-web-design/learn-typography-by-building-a-nutrition-label/step-41

Comment: El caso tiene que estar aqui.. si no, cuando borres ese pen, no vamos a saber de que hablabas y como se soluciona...

Comment: @gbianchi Lo intente pero me decia que era "demasiado codigo", y si lo acorto se rompe todo el html,se ve mal.Podria pasar captura de los html y css pero tengo entendido que es mala practica tambien

Comment: no.. entonces tenes que hacer un [mcve] para que se pueda replicar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu css elimina el:

```
.right {
    float: right;
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pregunta, sabes por que se desborda?es decir,si esta dentro de la caja label,no deberia simplemente flotarse a la derecha y ya?

Comment: es debido a que el div padre tiene la propiedad display:block y luego al hijo que el parrafo le das la propiedad float: right, esta propiedad hace que el elemento sea removido del flujo normal de la página, es decir no respeta el modelo de caja y se lo salta, por esta razon no respeta el encuadre. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: te comparto este link sobre el modelo de caja de CSS. [Modelo de Caja](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model)